# Grub 2 - attempting to boot into "Windows bootloader" boots me back into grub

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2

I've managed to dig myself into a bit of a hole.

When I boot, I am given the option to boot into Ubuntu or into the Windows bootloader. When I attempt using the windows bootloader, the result is that I am booted back into Grub, at the same menu.

Starting about a week ago, I tried installing Elementary OS, failed, and then subsequently installed Ubuntu 14.04. Since I believe it is relevant to my issue, here is the full "log" of what I have been doing:

- Installing Elementary OS about 4 times on a separate partition (with
  bootloader)
- Try making dual boot from Windows' BCD (through EasyBCD)
- Follow instructions to "boot-repair" once, creating dual boot but
  grub is broken and, when I booted I had to show it the proper config
  file on (hd0,7) (note: I have a UEFI system)
- Break Elementary OS by installing faulty drivers, reinstall
- Spend some time on Elementary OS, trying to make drivers work
- Attempt to boot into Windows, realize that it's not in the boot
  options
- Give up, install Ubuntu over the partitions that made up Elementary
  OS.
- Try booting into Windows - issue above happens.

Now, I would try reinstalling Windows - but then I'd have to go through the whole ordeal of going through 450 GB of data, finding what's worth backuping, reinstalling both Windows and Ubuntu again, reinstalling all my drivers, software, etc. There's also the issue of Windows being in a "hibernating" state, and I cannot stop that since I cannot boot into Windows.

I guess I'll take the time to make Ubuntu my home in the mean time :)